# Facing issue in boot Samsung SM-T555 android device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have a Samsung SM-T555 android device with OS version 5.0.2.

I have used `DevicePolicyManager` API of Android and made this device as device owner but its hanging. Also I tried to reboot the device but its stuck and I'm not able to reboot it.

I captured below logs from this device:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3512): FATAL EXCEPTION: Preference Handler Thread

E/AndroidRuntime( 3512): Process: com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver, PID: 3512

E/AndroidRuntime( 3512): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

E/AndroidRuntime( 3512):    at com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver.MountReceiver$1.handleMessage(MountReceiver.java:117)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3512):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3512):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3512):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

V/ApplicationPolicy(  851): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver

W/System.err( 3512): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.android.settings not found

W/ActivityManager(  851): Process com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver has crashed too many times: killing!

I/ActivityManager(  851): Killing 3512:com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver/1000 (adj 0): crash

D/ActivityManager(  851): startProcessLocked calleePkgName: com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver, hostingType: broadcast

W/BroadcastQueue(  851): Unable to launch app com.samsung.android.SettingsReceiver/1000 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }: process is bad
```